# How to get multiple instances of module in node.js?

Tags: node.js

In nodejs modules are singletons. I have created a module that takes configuration object and return some object. But at last I will be having single instance of the module. How to have multiple instances for different configurations?(each time they require, it should be different instance. How to achieve this?)

Answer (score 8):

Export a constructor and don't have implicit state:

Your current code looks something like:

```
module.exports = { ..}; // some object
```

Instead export a constructor:

```
module.exports = function(){
    // initialize module here, no global variables
    return { .. };
};
```

Comment: all variables defined in your .js file I thought based on how Node.js works, are are not global to begin with in a node module so no global variables doesn't make sense here.  They're not global even if you had defined variables outside the module.exports even

Comment: why are you returning the object?  I tried that but in the code requiring that module, it couldn't access any properties I put in that object.

Comment: @WeDoTDD sure exports are global, they're global across all `require`s of the module. `module.exports = "foo"` means I can `require("./myModule")` and access the exports anywhere. As for returning the object - you have to invoke the module as a function - like you normally call a constructor: `var fooBuilder = require("foo"); var foo = fooBuilder()` Or more concisely `var foo = require("foo")()` - this pattern is common for example in express.

Answer (score 4):

Return only constructors and have a dedicated module for the singletons:

lib/user.js:

```
module.exports = function () { ... }
```

lib/currentUser.js:

```
module.exports = new (require('./user'))();
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a module with that specific purpose, apart from providing the adding and retrieving you can define default arguments for your constructed items. 
Check it out [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/container.js)