# Session variable set in route middleware is not accessible throughout application in nodejs + concurrency issues

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, express, json-web-token

I am creating REST api's in nodejs with jsonwebtoken for authentication.Problem is I have created my own route middleware which decodes token and sets req.session as well as middleware object property to  the decoded token value but I can only access req.session in router.post() method but cannot access that sessiondata property set in middleware function.

Below is my sample code

user.js

```
 var router=require('express').Router();
 var AuthenticateLib=require('app/libraries/authentication');

 router.post('/updateprofile',AuthenticateLib.verifyToken,function(req,res){
  console.log(req.session); // is accessible over here
  console.log(AuthenticateLib.sessiondata) // prints null
});
```

authentication.js

```
  module.exports={
  sessiondata:null,
  verifyToken:function(req,res,next){
           var token = req.headers.authorization;
            return jwt.verifyAsync(token,config.getParam('security.jwtSecret'))
                    .then(decoded => {
                            req.session=decoded;
                            this.sessiondata=decoded;
                            next(); 
                    })
                    .catch(...)
       }}
```

I created sessiondata property because req object is not avaliable all over application so I thought may be I could require AuthenticateLib's  and access sessiondata property in my files wherever I need to access my session.

My aim is that I should be able to access my session data not only in router.post but in any other file in application.

I tried adding AuthenticateLib.sessiondata=req.session; just after router.post line then everything works fine but is it the only way.Why not sessiondata property set in middleware doesn't work.
Also how can I solve concurrency issues related to sessiondata property.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Even if it would work, `AuthenticateLib.sessiondata` is shared across all requests from what I can see, which means that your site can never support more than one concurrent user.

Comment: AuthenticateLib.sessiondata life would be only for that request of that user.So if multiple concurrent user are logged in there would be  multiple copies of AuthenticateLib.sessiondata as per user.correct me if I am wrong

Comment: You are wrong :) `AuthenticateLib.sessiondata` is the same property for each request, so it will be overwritten by each request that calls `verifyToken`, regardless on behalf of which user that request is made.

Comment: how can I fix it ?

Comment: "not easily", I'm afraid. Generally, `req` (or the data from `req` that is required) is passed around throughout the app.

Comment: how about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28833808/how-to-get-multiple-instances-of-module-in-node-js

Comment: You would still have to pass that newly created instance across your entire app, which isn't any different from passing `req`.

Comment: If there is no way to solve this problem what do u recommend further.should  I stick with node .Feel free to give ur advice.

Comment: You have to adjust your stated aim (to be able to access the session data everywhere without having to pass around at least _something_). Node.js apps require a different structure than, say, PHP apps. There are plenty of people that are perfectly happy using Node (I'm one of those people), but it's up to you if you are willing to conform to how it works.

Comment: I am ready to adjust my aim just show me the way.

Comment: _"pass `req` or the required data around as argument"_. Everywhere you need it. That's it.

Comment: I have posted my solution , let me know if it can cause any concurrency issues

Comment: No, I think you're fine now. It's still fundamentally the same as what I was suggesting, but instead of passing `req` around you have to pass `Obj` around (or encapsulate all the code that requires access to `mysessiondata` with that one function).

Comment: Thanks for your advice and identifying concurrency issue in the code :-)

Answer (score 0):

To solve the issue of concurrency I did something like

authentication.js

```
           function fname()
           {
             var x,y,mysessiondata; // all private vars
             return {
                     setsessiondata:function(data){mysessiondata=data;}, // public methods and vars
                     foo:function(){},.....   
             }
           }

           module.exports=fname;
```

Technically I didn't solve issue of session just modified my design pattern so that sessiondata would be set on every new obj created on each request which would be unique to each request which in turn solves my concurrency and overall session issue.

```
var AuthenticateLibObj=require('authentication');

 router.post('/updateprofile',AuthenticateLib.verifyToken,function(req,res){ 
          var Obj=new AuthenticateLibObj();
          Obj.setsessiondata(req.session);
          Obj.foo(); // so I dont need to pass session to foo again it can get it from its private datamember `mysessiondata`
          })
```